# How to annotate array of objects response in Swagger

Tags: java, swagger

I have to debug a REST API Java project that has been developed using Swagger.I'm new to it, so I'm a little bit confused on how to do certain things. For example, here's one method:

```
@GET
@Path("/location/name")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Operation(
    summary = "Get location information",
    tags = {"Information"},
    responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = LocationResponse.class)), description = "Get location information"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Error: Internal Server Error")
    }
)
public Response searchLocationByName(
    @Parameter(description = "Location name", required = true) @DefaultValue("Barcelona") @QueryParam("name") String locationName
) { /* METHOD CODE */ }
```

The `@ApiResponse` for the code 200 is not of type `LocationResponse` but of type `ArrayList<LocationResponse>`, as it can return more than one location. What would be the correct syntax for this change? I've been reading the documentation at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#operation-annotations but I couldn't find an appropriate example...

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`@ArraySchema`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#arrayschema) instead of plain `@Schema` to [define input or output data for array types](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#media).

Comment: I saw the `@ArraySchema` annotation but I misunderstood the documentation and I thought that it wasn't what I needed... my fault. Now it's working with this annotation: `@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content = @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = LocationResponse.class))), description = "Get location information"),`. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer. Related question: How does it work with generics in general? e.g. PageDto<ItemDto> ? Currently I can only provide PageDto.class. Is there a a way to provide type information to swagger? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For the `PageDto<T>` we can simply create `ResponseDto` which extends `PageDto<T>` and use it in swagger as :

```
@ApiResponse(
  responseCode = "200",
  content = @Content(
  array = 
    @ArraySchema(
      schema = @Schema(implementation = ResponseDto.class))), 
      description = "Get location information"),
```

Comment: As a workaround I accept that. However I would assume there should be a way to do this without creating more classes just to make the documentation correctly understand the code. I opened a ticket to further investigate this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3851

Answer (score 2):

Code should look like this !!

```
@ApiResponses(
    value = {
      @ApiResponse(
          responseCode = "200",
          description = "Successful operation",
          content = @Content(
              mediaType = "application/json",
              array = @ArraySchema(
              schema = @Schema(implementation = LocationResponse.class))))
})
```